# Defining then() after promise has been retrieved

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angular-promise

I have a question about attaching callback functions to promises in AngularJS.

Suppose I have a service with a function that returns a promise. I make a call to this function and store the promise locally. Then I define a callback function on the promise.

```
var promise = TestService.get();
console.log('We have a promise!');
promise.then(function (result){
  console.log('Here is the result:'+result);
});
```

In this case, we have a potentially risky situation. If the promise is resolved before we get to `promise.then(...`, the result is not outputted to the console (until the next digest cycle).

Alternatively, I could write the above code like this:

```
TestService.get().then(function (result){
  console.log('Here is the result:'+result);
});
```

My question:

Has the risk been mitigated in the second example? And if not, how can I make sure that the promise does not resolve before I have attached a callback?
A slightly more elaborate answer than yes/no would be much appreciated :)

Comment: You're talking of "digest cycles". Are you asking specifically about AngularJS promises? And what exactly is your problem?

Comment: There is no difference in behaviour between your two snippets. The callback will always be executed, and always asynchronously.

Comment: That is correct, see the first sentence of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior you are describing does not occur, that can be seen through a simple example.  Here we have a simple promise factory which returns a promise which resolves immediately.

```
'use strict';
var make = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(2);
  });
};
```

Then we create a new promise and assign it to a variable

```
var prom = make();
```

We can call .then on it as many times as we want.  This is because promises are immutable, we don't change the original value by chaining methods on it.

```
prom.then(a => console.log(a));
// 2
prom.then(a => console.log(a));
// 2
```

Comment: The then handler is always executed async. This means that your function will always return before it gets into that handler (regardless of whether the promise has resolved or is still pending).

Comment: @Jonah Thanks for the answer! My question arose while unit-testing my service with Karma. By calling `$httpBackend.flush()` before the callback was defined, I would cause the situation I have described in my question.

Answer (score 2):

> Suppose I have a service with a function that returns a promise. I make a call to this function and store the promise locally. Then I define a callback function on the promise.

No, you are not attaching a callback. When you call the **then** method you are doing something called *promise chaining*. Each call to *then* returns a **new** promise object that will resolve to the value returned by the previous promise.

For example;

```
var promise1 = TestService.get();
var promise2 = promise1.then(function(value) {
                  console.log('service resolved: '+value);
                  return "Hello World";
               });
var promise3 = promise2.then(function(value) {
                  console.log(value);
               });
promise3.then(function(value) {
       console.log(value);
});
```

The above example will output the following.

```
**some value from TestService**
Hello World
undefined
```

We don't know who originally resolve the value for the first promise. All we know is that the service returned a promise. From that moment on we can chain the promises by adding more calls to *then*.

> In this case, we have a potentially risky situation. If the promise is resolved before we get to promise.then(..., the result is not outputted to the console (until the next digest cycle).

No, it does not matter when or what digest the promise is resolved. A promise can have it's *then* method called multiple times even after being resolved. It will continue to resolve to the value as long as it has not been rejected. The decision to resolve or reject a promise is outside the scope of the success or failure callbacks.

You can create a promise, resolve it to a value, wait several digests and add a handler to *then* and it will still work as expected.

> Has the risk been mitigated in the second example? And if not, how can I make sure that the promise does not resolve before I have attached a callback?

Think of promises as **containers**. They are going to hold the value you expect, and you have to call *then* to get it. If for what ever reason the value is unavailable you can find out why by using the *error* callback. The **when** aspect of promises is purely an asynchronize issue, and the idea is for promises to *hide* those issues.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is not multithreaded, your asynchronous AJAX call isn't  actually made by the browser until your code returns.

```
var promise = TestService.get();
for (var i= 0;i<100000;i++){
    console.log(i)
}
console.log('We have a promise!');
promise.then(function (result){
    console.log('Here is the result:'+result);
});
```

Watch this with the network analyzer.